# Multiple different cURL calls in a specific order

Tags: php, curl

I'm familiar with cURL loading a single webpage, but in this case, I need two URL's loaded about 3 times (in a specific order). I don't know what is the best and cleanest way to handle multiple cURL calls, are there any tips and tricks for this?

For example cURL first calls 'file1.php', once it has COMPLETELY finished loading (important!), it will call 'file2.php'.

This process needs to be repeated about 3 times. I was thinking of putting the process above inside a loop, however just like in the process, the files may not be called yet when the previous is not finished loading yet. I prefer to even have a little sleep() between them. It is really important that the files are loaded in a specific order each time.

Can anybody who's experienced with cURL point me towards the right position? I honestly have no idea where to start.